# Facebook Login through C#

Tags: c#, facebook, visual-studio

I'm a new starter to C# and trying to add Login through Facebook function to my basic website. Users can login through Facebook but when they change pages let's say from Home to About Us page, they need to click log in again. How can I change the code to make sure that when they go to other pages they still see logged in and account details? Sorry if it is a basic question and thanks for your understanding.

Here is my C# code;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using ASPSnippets.FaceBookAPI;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

public partial class UserControls_WebUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{

    protected void btn_fblogin_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        FaceBookConnect.Authorize("user_photos,email", Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Split('?')[0]);

    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FaceBookConnect.API_Key = "111111111111";
        FaceBookConnect.API_Secret = "1111111111111";
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Request.QueryString["error"] == "access_denied")
            {
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('User has denied access.')", true);
                return;
            }

            string code = Request.QueryString["code"];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(code))
            {
                string data = FaceBookConnect.Fetch(code, "me");
                FaceBookUser faceBookUser = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<FaceBookUser>(data);
                faceBookUser.PictureUrl = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/{0}/picture", faceBookUser.Id);
                pnl_fblogin.Visible = true;
                lbl_name.Text = faceBookUser.Name;
                profile_image.ImageUrl = faceBookUser.PictureUrl;
                btn_fblogin.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public class FaceBookUser
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string PictureUrl { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }               

    protected void btn_fblogout_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        FaceBookConnect.Logout(Request.QueryString["code"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: why not use the javascript sdk for this? it is so much easier to handle than doing all that stuff on your server. especially with c#, facebook does not even have an official sdk for that.

Comment: for example: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: Unfortunately that's the task I've been given, I need to do this in c#

Comment: Use the [Facebook SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Facebook)

Comment: well, all you have to do is store the access token and reuse it on other pages